# getFilter() throws Null Pointer Exception (probably because of initialization adapter,couldn't solve it)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

This time I'm facing another issue I'm trying to filter with search in RecyclerView and most likely because I don't know how to initialize the adapter while keeping the other methods normal,I've done my research and this is my final code for Main3Activity;

```
private static final String TAG = "Main3Activity";
private final String JSON_URL = "https://MYURLXXX" ;
private JsonArrayRequest request ;
private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
private RecyclerViewLiveAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
    jsonrequest();



}

private void jsonrequest() {

    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {


                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                    Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                    anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                    anime.setRating(jsonObject.getString("Rating"));
                    anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("categorie"));
                    anime.setStudio(jsonObject.getString("studio"));
                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("img"));
                    anime.setLink(jsonObject.getString("link"));
                    anime.setDrm_scheme(jsonObject.getString("drm_scheme"));
                    anime.setDrm_license_url(jsonObject.getString("drm_license_url"));
                    anime.setDrm(jsonObject.getString("drm"));
                    anime.setSubtitle(jsonObject.getString("subtitle"));
                    anime.setSubtitle1(jsonObject.getString("subtitle1"));
                    anime.setSubtitle2(jsonObject.getString("subtitle2"));
                    lstAnime.add(anime);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);


            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Main3Activity.this);
    requestQueue.add(request) ;


}

private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {


    RecyclerViewLiveAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewLiveAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (adapter == null){
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);}
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}
```

}

and the filter part in my adapter;

```
   @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return exampleFilter;
}

private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<Anime> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(mDataFull);
        } else {
            String filterpattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (Anime anime : mDataFull) {
                if (anime.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterpattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(anime);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        mData.clear();
        mData.addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
```

As you can see I use a method called setuprecyclerview(); this method after getting the JSON response,initializes the adapter.But with this code without changing anything it's impossible to set adapter after filtering

```
if (adapter == null){
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);}
            return false;
```

If I change `adapter == null` to `adapter != null` search function and keyboard pops-up but it doesn't fire the filter event,whole recyclerview stays same.So when I keep it as adapter == null it throws a NPE,if you look down below you'll see that getFilter in my Adapter is null because I can't make adapter initialized after the filtering.So,how can I achieve this while keeping the other methods same and safe ? Which parts I have to change ? Thanks in advance.

```
2019-03-13 02:23:56.374 27544-27544/com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication, PID: 27544
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication.adapters.RecyclerViewLiveAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
    at com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication.activities.Main3Activity$3.onQueryTextChange(Main3Activity.java:138)
    at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1180)
    at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1714)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:9413)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5086)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4908)
    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:110)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4883)
    at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onActionViewExpanded(SearchView.java:1294)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter.expandItemActionView(Toolbar.java:2396)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.expandItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java:1348)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.expandActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:810)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:978)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to a null adapter object. No need to create an instance for adapter again in setuprecyclerview() method since you already created a global reference variable for it. Instead do as below,

```
 private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {
    adapter = new RecyclerViewLiveAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Also, you should check for this adapter object is not null in onQueryTextChange() method.

```
if (adapter != null){
     adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
}
```

Comment: Dude,you are the best,it worked like a charm.It was right in front of my eyes,how could I miss it by the way ? Need to take a break ,:)

Comment: Dude,can  you also take a look at this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133272/searchview-after-voice-implemantation-throws-nullpointerexception