# SearchView After Voice Implemantation throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, searchview

I tried to implement Voice Search by following steps here; [ActionBar Mic Button(Voice Search) in SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370655/actionbar-mic-buttonvoice-search-in-searchview?answertab=votes#3)

Everything is fine,I've added all necessary info to my AndroidManifest and searcabhle.xml so I'm able to see mic icon and Search Bar,the problem is when I try to search with voice after saying something,it doesn't find anything and app crashes,looks like something wrong with SetQuery and here's the full error;

```
2019-03-13 04:55:55.723 1533-1533/com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication, PID: 1533
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setQuery(java.lang.CharSequence, boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication.activities.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:153)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1243)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:3064)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:3076)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:3085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

And this is my Main3Activity;

```
 private static final String TAG = "Main3Activity";
private final String JSON_URL = "https://MYURLXXX" ;
private JsonArrayRequest request ;
private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
private RecyclerViewLiveAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
        jsonrequest();



    }

    private void jsonrequest() {

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {


                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                        Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                        anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                        anime.setRating(jsonObject.getString("Rating"));
                        anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("categorie"));
                        anime.setStudio(jsonObject.getString("studio"));
                        anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("img"));
                        anime.setLink(jsonObject.getString("link"));
                        anime.setDrm_scheme(jsonObject.getString("drm_scheme"));
                        anime.setDrm_license_url(jsonObject.getString("drm_license_url"));
                        anime.setDrm(jsonObject.getString("drm"));
                        anime.setSubtitle(jsonObject.getString("subtitle"));
                        anime.setSubtitle1(jsonObject.getString("subtitle1"));
                        anime.setSubtitle2(jsonObject.getString("subtitle2"));
                        lstAnime.add(anime);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);


                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Main3Activity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request) ;


    }

    private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {


        adapter = new RecyclerViewLiveAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (adapter != null){
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);}
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;

    }

   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            searchView.setQuery(query, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I do filtering stuff in my adapter but since error happens here, I think there's no need to put my adapter code here and also because filtering with text works perfectly, the only problem is voice search.

Comment: You can see the onNewIntent method at the bottom of MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are accessing a null searchView object in onNewIntent(). Create a global reference variable for `searchView` in your class and instantiate in onCreateOptionsMenu(). Like below:

```
SearchView searchView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (adapter != null){
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);}
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Again you're the best ! And another silly mistake,I've already created the global reference for searchView in my last code but I forgot to update related part inside the onCreateOptionsMenu.